# How do I display *all* the filters in layered navigation?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, mage, layered-navigation

I am using "Layered Navigation SEO" from magento connect.
It's working flawlessly.

But I want the filters(with results) to be displayed always. My requirement is not similar to other questions found here.

for example...

In the computers category (working with sample data) there are 4 brands and three colors (black, brown and silver)
I select "Apple" as brand the available colors would be silver alone, but I want to display all the 3 colors as before (remember... NOT all the colors like pink, magenta, etc.)
If I select filter(no results) all colors like white, magento, pink, etc. will be displayed, which I don't want

I want only the filters which are related to category initially.
I am new to magento coding

Any help?

If more clarity is needed I'll be able to provide...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in app\code\local\Catalin\SEO\Model\Catalog\Resource\Layer\Filter\Attribute.php

edit public function getCount($filter)

goto last line

change return $connection->fetchPairs($select); to...

```
$pairCarry = $connection->fetchPairs($select);
$pairCarryfin = $this->checkTheAttributes($pairCarry, $tableAlias, $attribute); 
 return $pairCarryfin;
```

then add the function below it...

```
public function checkTheAttributes($pairCarry, $tableAlias, $attribute){
    $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
    if($category){
        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT `$tableAlias`.`value`, COUNT($tableAlias.entity_id) AS `count` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
         INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=".$category->getStoreId()." AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='".$category->getId()."'
         INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
         INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `$tableAlias` ON $tableAlias.entity_id = e.entity_id AND $tableAlias.attribute_id = '".$attribute->getAttributeId()."' AND $tableAlias.store_id = '".$category->getStoreId()."' GROUP BY `$tableAlias`.`value`";
    }
    else{
        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT `$tableAlias`.`value`, COUNT($tableAlias.entity_id) AS `count` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
         INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4)
         INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
         INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `$tableAlias` ON $tableAlias.entity_id = e.entity_id AND $tableAlias.attribute_id = '".$attribute->getAttributeId()."' AND $tableAlias.store_id = 1 GROUP BY `$tableAlias`.`value`";
    }
    $connection = $this->_getReadAdapter();
    $pairCarry_inter = $connection->fetchPairs($query);

    if(!empty($pairCarry)){
        $odd = array_diff_key($pairCarry_inter, $pairCarry);
        if(!empty($odd)){
            foreach($odd as $k=>$v){
                $odd[$k] = 0;
            }
        $pairCarry_inter = $pairCarry + $odd;
        }
    }

    else{
        foreach($pairCarry_inter as $k => $v){
            $pairCarry_inter[$k] = 0;
        }
    }

    $pairCarry_complete = $pairCarry_inter;

    return $pairCarry_complete;
}
```